# Are .NET Decimal type computations deterministic?

Tags: .net, floating-point, type-conversion, decimal, deterministic

I have two questions regarding .NET's `decimal` data type determinism:

1. Are `decimal` type computations cross-platform deterministic? Or in other words, will math operations on `decimal` type produce exactly the same results on all platforms?
2. Is casting `decimal` number to `float` or `double` cross-platform deterministic (casts will always produce exactly the same result)?

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised to see some differences in corner cases between Mono and the Microsoft implementations...

Comment: Indeed, [there was a bug in the Mono implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414708/precision-of-c-sharp-decimal-type-division-is-different-on-mono) that caused different results compared to the Windows one. I would expect others.

Comment: As far as I know, the answers to both questions could be yes. No guarantee. However, there is an issue with conversion to `double` in relation to trailing zeroes of the `decimal`. It is possible to have two `decimal` values that only differ by the number of trailing zeroes, and therefore these two `decimal`s are considered equal (even if they have distinct internal representations), such that when you convert them to `double`, the resulting `double` values are distinct. _Addition:_ This also proves that the conversion to `double` does not always pick the nearest destination. Want example?

Comment: It would indeed be good to see an example: that doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @Bathsheba An example: `var a = ((double)200.000000000000000000000M).ToString("R"); var b = ((double)200.0000000000000000000000M).ToString("R"); var c = ((double)200.00000000000000000000000M).ToString("R");`. Taken from [late answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23638323/1336654). Because the `System.Decimal` implementation of `GetHashCode()` works by first converting to `double` and then truncating that `double` a bit, the decimal involved in `a` here even has the wrong `decimal.GetHashCode()`. The other two have the right hash code.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for. So custom numeric data type is the only way to get cross-platform deterministic computations that have numbers with fractional part in .NET. Reinventing the wheel for all non-basic math operations that go with that custom data type is the tougher part I think.

Comment: I guess, *apart from bugs*, decimals should be deterministic, since they are implemented in .NET, floats and doubles are probably not, because they are computed on the CPU (which is at best following an standard). Casts involve both and I wouldn't expect them to be deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of fear-mongering in the comments to this question.

First, there's the fear of a certain Mono bug sometime in the past. Not only has that been already fixed, but *just don't use Mono in 2021*. Both .Net Core and .Net5 are fully cross-platform.

Then there's the fear that `GetHashCode` can return equal values for non-equal decimal instances. Yes, that's how `GetHashCode` (and indeed, all hash functions) work, otherwise you could compress any arbitrary data type to 4 bytes. Instead of typing all that, I recommend reading a book on hashing.

To the OP, there's no need to either listen to those people or reinvent `decimal`. It's perfectly safe to use.

Comment: `GetHashCode can return true for non-equal decimal instances` no need to rephrase. Re-read?

Comment: Okay fine, hopefully that clarification helps OP understand the state of `decimal` better.